# Doctrine - encryption with dql listeners

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, doctrine, dql

I am attempting to encrypt certain database fields by adding a call to mysql `AES_ENCRYPT` (and `AES_DECRYPT`) using Doctrine DQL Hooks.

for SQL `SELECT`'s I have a `preDqlSelect()` in my `Doctrine_Record_Listener` class, which goes through each parameter in the select fields, and adds a `AES_DECRYPT()` for encrypted fields.

But, it looks like calling `save()` on a doctrine model class only calls the `preSave()` listener and does not call any of the preDql* listeners.

Can anyone suggest a way of getting this to work or a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order for these dql callbacks to be checked, you must explicitly turn them on. Because this adds a small amount of overhead for each query, it is off by default

```
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_USE_DQL_CALLBACKS, true);
```

[Doctrine 1.2 Event listeners](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/event-listeners/en#record-listeners)